# iPhone add music to the app through web downloads. Where to start?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, download

I have an app ready to publish, and it's size is creeping dangerously close to 20mb. As far as I understand, at 20mb it can no longer be downloaded over the air, which I expect has  a pretty big impact on the number of downloads (I personally have never went through the trouble of trying to download any app again over Wifi if I cannot get it OTA).

**I'm trying to add multiple sound files to my app**. Doing so would push it over 20mb. **How would I go about downloading music from my website in a secure manner?** I think the licencing terms would not let me just put it on the website and let people download it. It has to be somehow authenticated and only let my app download the file.

Is there any kind of hosting service that lets me put a file online and authenticate my app before letting the app download it?

Thank you for any input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should understand that any authentication mechanism can be reverse-engineered. However I think your files aren't so important so it will be ok if you just obfuscate URL in your source code.

Comment: Yeah, I just don't want to get into legal trouble if somehow the files that are licensed to me are suddenly floating all over the web

Comment: I think then the most important thing is that you do not intentionally redistribute them. Since reverse-engineering is usually prohibited, it's not your problem if someone reverse-engineer your app and get files or URLs.